# How to grep through many files of same file type

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, grep

I wish to grep through many (20,000) text files, each with about 1,000,000 lines each, so the faster the better.

I have tried the below code and it just doesn't seem to want to do anything, it doesn't find any matches even after an hour (it should have done by now).

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do  grep -Ff firstpart.txt $1; done
```

Comment: How many lines are in firstpart.txt?

Comment: About 2500 or so

Comment: What happens if you just search for the first pattern in the file?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ripgrep` is the most amazing tool. You should get that and use it.

To search `*.txt` files in all directories recursively, do this:

```
rg -t txt -f patterns.txt
```

Ripgrep uses one of the fastest regular expression engines out there. It uses multiple threads. It searches directories and files, and filters them to the interesting ones in the fastest way.

It is simply great.

For anyone stuck using `grep` for whatever reason:

```
find -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P 8 -n 8 grep -Ff patterns.txt
```

That tells `xargs` to `-n 8` use 8 arguments per command and to `-P 8` run 8 copies in parallel. It has the downside that the output might become interleaved and corrupted.

Instead of xargs you could use `parallel` which does a fancier job and keeps output in order:

```
$ find -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | parallel -0  grep --with-filename grep -Ff patterns.txt
```

Comment: This is actually perfect, using it now.. superb, thanks.

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful for folks that must use grep which is widely available and portable. GNU grep is actually very fast, not that much slower than ripgrep, especially when using option `-F`. GNU grep does not run parallel threads though, but performance is dictated by the speed (or lack thereof) of the file system anyway, not by how fast the search tool runs. Also, I found that ripgrep is not compatible to GNU grep, meaning it is not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE The question seemed to be using "grep" as a verb, not as an actual requirement to use `grep`

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE And also, parallel threads are a great thing since most of my systems these days use NVMe SSD storage. 8 - 32 simultaneous reads are perfect.

Comment: @ZanLynx Theoretically ripgrep may run faster with 2 or more threads, which would be under ideal circumstances assuming parallel file reading isn't causing some contention that may be observed. Not to put a finger on anything here, but there are lots of ways to improve (or fudge) performance results, e.g. when files were already accessed and consequently file reading is sped up due to massive caching. Also, BSD grep is known to be slower than GNU grep. Perhaps the OP uses BSD grep? It might be fun to explore the performance of edge cases like this (i.e. option `-F)` further.

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE I can assure you that on NVMe SSDs you get performance boost up to 8 threads or even more. One CPU core simply cannot run a regex as fast as NVMe can stream data.

Comment: @ZanLynx The speedup is fundamentally limited by the number of cores, assuming each thread executes reasonably efficiently without latencies due to IO delays, pipeline hazards, etc. A quick test shows this on a Qt directory with 32,480 files over 2.3GB total. Executing `time ggrep -r -F TODO . >/dev/null` on a typical system 2.8Ghz i7 16GB LPDDR3 with 256GB SSD takes 1.8 seconds (warm start). Ripgrep takes 0.6 seconds (warm start). So 3x faster, not 8x. Hardly going from hours to seconds of searching. Also, a cold start can be at least 20% to several times slower, resulting in lower speedups.

Answer (score 4):

Ofir's answer is good. Another option:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -fnFH firstpart.txt {} \;
```

I like to add the `-n` for line numbers and `-H` to get the filename. `-H` is particularly useful in this case as you could have a lot of matches.

Comment: If your `find` supports it it'd be faster to use `+` instead of `\;` at the end of the command as then grep would be called with multiple input files at once instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating through the files in a loop, you can just give the file names to grep using xargs and let grep go over all the files.

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep $1
```

I'm not quite sure whether it will actually increase the performance, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: This breaks for filenames with blanks in them, and the `$1` doesn't really do anything here, does it? I assume it's from the question, where it actually should have been `$i` anyway. This should be something like `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`.